# Copy two columns from one Excel sheet to another

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I need to copy two columns of one Excel sheet to the same columns of another Excel sheet using VBScript. These columns are adjacent to each other
I am using the following code, which I got from by some search and changed to my need. It is working fine if it is to copy one column but it is not copying two columns from one excel to another.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Customer.xlsx")
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Folder1\Test.xlsx")

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

Set objRange = objWorkSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn
Set objRange = objWorkSheet.Range("B1").EntireColumn
objRange.Copy

Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

Set objRange = objWorkSheet2.Range("A1")
Set objRange = objWorkSheet2.Range("B1")
objWorksheet.Paste(objRange)
```

My Input Excel file is:

```
Customer Number    Customer Name
1001    Wendy
1002    Subway
1003    McDonalds
```

My output Excel file has the same column names but is presently have no values in these columns. After copying from the input Excel, I should have the same values to the these columns in the second Excel file.

Comment: Your code is VBA not VBScript. See the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info) and [here](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers....sorry I thought it is the same. How should I implement it using VB Script. I want this in VBScript. Please apologize for being novice.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers...Yes I did and now I am trying to create a VB Script

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have edited my post with a new code which works fine to copy one column but does not copy two columns. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Set objRange = objWorkSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn
> Set objRange = objWorkSheet.Range("B1").EntireColumn
> ```

The above two statements first select column A, then select column B. To select 2 columns use something like this:

```
Set objRange = objWorkSheet.Range("A:B").EntireColumn
```

You don't even need to assign the selection to a variable. Simply call the methods on the objects:

```
objWorkSheet.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Copy
objWorkSheet2.Paste objWorkSheet2.Range("A1")
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is copying two columns now but I have got another challenge. In this process, it opens the excel files and don't
 close it or preferably do that in the back ground. I have updated my post with a new code which does not get me what I want