# automatically opening and closing Excel files while copying columns

Tags: vbscript

I have a VB Script which copies two columns from one excel to the same columns of another excel file. While doing so, it opens up 
excel files, which I don't want. Preferably, I want this to happen in the background and if not possible, then I want it to close it automatically
after completing the procedure.
I tried to update my code to accomplish this task but it has started throwing pop ups. One of which reads as 
"There is large amount of information in the clipboard......" and second pop up asks me if I want to save the changes in file.
I want all this automatically, no manual interaction.
I want the whole procedure to happen without any manual intervention

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Folder1\Customer.xlsx")
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Folder2\New_Customer.xlsx")

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

Set objRange = objWorkSheet.Range("A:B").EntireColumn
objWorkSheet.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Copy

Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Activate

Set objRange = objWorkSheet2.Range("A:B")
objWorkSheet2.Paste objWorkSheet2.Range("A:B")
objWorksheet.Paste(objRange)

objworkbook.Saved = True

objWorkbook.close("C:\Desktop\Folder1\Customer.xlsx")
objWorkbook2.close("C:\Documents\Folder2\New_Customer.xlsx")
```

My Input file looks like:

```
Customer Number    Customer Name
1001    Wendy
1002    Subway
1003    McDonalds
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. The following solution should do what you want.
Please note:

- `objworkbook.Saved = True` - This means will don't want to save any changes
- `objworkbook.Save` - This means you DO want to save changes

I added both lines in the code below, so you can choose which one do you want and delete the other.

**EDIT :** I updated the code below. 
I'm assuming you want to discard any changes in objWorkbook and save your changes to objWorkbook2.
I don't understand what you are trying to do in the `objWorkbook.close` part, but I left it unchanged.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False   ' This is the value that decides if process should run on background or not. Keep as False if you don't want to display the application
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Folder1\Customer.xlsx")
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Folder2\New_Customer.xlsx")

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)

objWorksheet.Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Copy
objWorksheet2.Paste objWorksheet2.Range("A1")

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False ' This will make Excel stop showing any warnings
objworkbook.Saved = True  ' This means you don't want to save changes
objWorkbook2.Save         ' This means you want to save changes.

' I don't understand what you are trying to do here, but I'm not changing this
objWorkbook.close("C:\Desktop\Folder1\IHT_PIM_STATUS_TEST.xlsx\Customer.xlsx")
objWorkbook2.close("C:\Documents\Folder2\New_Customer.xlsx")

objExcel.Quit    ' Close excel application after the whole process
```

Comment: ....Thanks now I don't see Excel files getting opened but at the same time, I don't see the desired result. This code is not copying the columns from one excel to that of another excel.

Comment: I assumed by your previous question, answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938748/copy-two-columns-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another), that your code was already working, so I only showed you how to make the whole process on the background (that was your question, wasn't it?). Anyway, I have edited my answer. Please try it and let me know if works now

Comment: Yes the code was already working but after adding the code for background, it stopped

Comment: When I remove the following lines of code then the code copies the columns from one excel to another. However, I get two pop ups as mentioned earlier in my post.                                           objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 
objworkbook.Saved = True

Comment: Keep the line `objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False` and change the other one to `obkWorkbook.Save`

Comment: Victor Moraes, As before when I add this code, then I don't see expected results. Nothing gets copied over from on excel to another